# Why isn't replace working in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to parse some data and I cannot seem to use `.replace` to remove the junk i.e. `[Bluray]` and other data that is not year or resolution. My end goal is end up with columns of: Movie Name, Year and Resolution

```
,Movie Name,others
0,James Bond The Spy Who Loved Me ,1977) [1080p]
1,James Bond Live And Let Die ,1973) [1080p]
2,No Time To Die ,2021) [1080p] [BluRay] [5.1] [YTS.MX]
3,James Bond The Man With The Golden Gun ,1974) [1080p]
4,Casino Royale ,2006) [2160p] [4K] [BluRay] [5.1] [YTS.MX]
5,James Bond Moonraker ,1979) [1080p]
6,James Bond Licence To Kill ,1989) [1080p]
7,James Bond A View To A Kill ,1985) [1080p]
8,James Bond The Living Daylights ,1987) [1080p]
```

Code i'm using is:

`df['others']=df['others'].replace(to_replace=[['','BluRay']],value='')`

Can anyone see where i'm going wrong?

Comment: It's `.str.replace(...)`

Comment: Not according to this: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

Comment: See https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas.Series.str.replace

Comment: `.replace()` is for matching and replacing the entire field, `.str.replace()` is for replacing substrings.

Comment: I think you're focusing too much on what you want to remove, and not enough on what you want to keep. My answer addresses extracting what you want to keep~

Comment: @Noobcoder, was I off in my solution? I just updated your code to accomplish your stated goal .

Comment: @Naveed Unfortunately no. It left in a lot of other bits I didn't need. BeRT2me's solution seems to do the trick.

Comment: I got it! This did the trick: `df4[["Movie Name","Year","Resolution"]]=df4["Movie Name"].str.extract(r'(.*?(?=\s\()).*(\d{4}).*(\d{4}p)')` It outputs three crisp columns of Movie name, Year and Resolution. Very exciting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
                                Movie Name                                      others
0         James Bond The Spy Who Loved Me                                1977) [1080p]
1             James Bond Live And Let Die                                1973) [1080p]
2                          No Time To Die        2021) [1080p] [BluRay] [5.1] [YTS.MX]
3  James Bond The Man With The Golden Gun                                1974) [1080p]
4                           Casino Royale   2006) [2160p] [4K] [BluRay] [5.1] [YTS.MX]
5                    James Bond Moonraker                                1979) [1080p]
6              James Bond Licence To Kill                                1989) [1080p]
7             James Bond A View To A Kill                                1985) [1080p]
8         James Bond The Living Daylights                                1987) [1080p]
```

To clean this up I would do:

```
df['Movie Name'] = df['Movie Name'].str.strip()
df[['Year', 'Resolution']] = df['others'].str.extract('(\d{4})\).*\[(.*p)]')

print(df[['Movie Name', 'Year', 'Resolution']])
```

Output:

```
                               Movie Name  Year Resolution
0         James Bond The Spy Who Loved Me  1977      1080p
1             James Bond Live And Let Die  1973      1080p
2                          No Time To Die  2021      1080p
3  James Bond The Man With The Golden Gun  1974      1080p
4                           Casino Royale  2006      2160p
5                    James Bond Moonraker  1979      1080p
6              James Bond Licence To Kill  1989      1080p
7             James Bond A View To A Kill  1985      1080p
8         James Bond The Living Daylights  1987      1080p
```

Comment: For an explanation of the regex, see [Regexr](https://regexr.com/6n1pk)

Comment: Hi Bert, thanks for the reply. It does exactly what I want it to, but i'm struggling to understand the regex. Can you perchance update the answer with a breakdown of what each bit is doing? Thanks.

Comment: Here's the best I could do (needed two lines): `\[.{0,3}\]` and `[^(\d{4}p?)]`, where the first part I needed specifically to handle `[5.1]`

Comment: Edit: I just noticed you used `extract`. I was trying to do this with a `replace` and replace the parts I didn't need. Your way is much simpler! Wish I understood the regex though!

Comment: @Noobcoder check out the link I posted in my comment, it explicitly describes what each piece of the regex is doing~